# pip で公開するパッケージ(プロジェクト)の名称について、推奨される規約 (convention) はありますか？

Tags: python, pip

pip で新しくパッケージを公開したいとします。その名称、特に https://pypi.org/ にて公開することになるパッケージ(プロジェクト)の名称について、推奨される規約などはありますでしょうか？ 例えば、アルファベットと数字以外の文字については、どこまでが許容されるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

パッケージング時のメタデータに配布名として使用できる文字は以下のとおりです:

- ASCII文字([a-zA-Z])
- ASCII数字([0-9])
- アンダースコア(_)
- ハイフン(-)
- ピリオド(.)

そのほかに、
先頭と末尾はASCII文字または数字でなければなりません。
自動化ツールにおいては、これに従わない名称はリジェクトするよう求められています。
大文字小文字は区別されますが、ハイフンとアンダースコアは同等とみなされます。
などなど…
とのことです。

[PEP 426 -- Metadata for Python Software Packages 2.0](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#name)

その他参考:
[PEP 423 -- Naming conventions and recipes related to packaging](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#use-packaging-metadata)